# Attaching dresser mirror with metal rails

Tags: mounting, mirror

Does anyone have experience with the mounting a mirror using the type of rails (*Rite-View®*) and brackets shown in the pictures below? It seems fairly straightforward but I have a few questions:

[image: Dresser Top and Rails]

[image: Back of Mirror]

1. What is the correct position of the mirror? Should the bottom of the mirror be installed flush with the dresser top or does it not matter? Based on the screw marks on the rails it looks like the previous owner had this raised up a bit but I've not seen one like pictured like this before.
2. What is the correct position of the mirror rails?  There is a slot and some holes at each end that look like they *could be* intended to interact with the brackets screws in some way. It's hard to tell.

Is there a *"correct"* alignment/position for this hardware or is it solely down to personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given us much to go on from those pictures, but having assembled and installed a headboard on my bead recently with a similar type system:

> What is the correct position of the mirror?

Those rails do not look sturdy enough to support the entire weight of a mirror and prevent it from falling over. I'd submit that the mirror should be resting on the dresser below and that the rails are simply to keep it in place.

> What is the correct position of the mirror rails?

It does appear that the screws through the brackets are intended to go into the holes shown in the picture of the rails, but I'd suggest that those holes are actually to mount the rails to the back of the dresser and that the screws in the brackets simply hold the rails in position once the mirror has been set on the dresser.

The top of the rail should mount near the top bracket on the mirror. Then they should extend as far as possible below the edge of the mirror that they can provide solid leverage where screwed into the dresser to act as a lever to keep the mirror from falling over.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  The rails are actually fairly think steel and very sturdy.  I'm not sure what kind of pictures you're looking for.  I've seen a bunch of older units with this type of mounting system in the past so I know they're common enough that someone out there might have had direct experience with them.

Comment: I ended up doing pretty much exactly what you suggested here. On assembling it I realized that the brackets on the mirror aren't even installed in the same place relative to one another so it's likely that the previous owner installed these themself.  Sliding the rails so that they go through both brackets on the mirror and extend down as far as possible without projecting past the bottom of the unit resulted in a very stable feel. I think ideally there should be two brackets on the base unit as well but I think it's ok as is.

Comment: I would agree with you, @billynoah. A second bracket lower on the back of the dresser would help prevent the mirror from tipping forward. However, dressers are generally pushed up against a wall, so the wall itself will help prevent the tipping - the mirror can only go as far forward as the bottom of the rail will allow it before hitting the wall. This could lead to the rail damaging the wall, but that's still better than the mirror falling and shattering on the bedroom floor.

Comment: Glad you got this worked out.